# Use OxyPlot in Windows Universal app c++/xaml project

Tags: c#, c++, win-universal-app, oxyplot

I am new to windows app development. I want to use OxyPlot in UWAP C++/Xaml project. I am able to use it in C# based project but not in C++/Xaml project. First I tried to add it using Nuget package manager but it didn't install. Then I followed this (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b77c775-21e0-4b43-b9f3-fb3777c43212/adding-libraries-and-use-them?forum=winappswithnativecode). In this Windows runtime component (with OxyPlot) is created in C# and used in C++ project. Here I am able to build the project but app crashes saying OxyPlot (added in C# project) not found.

Can someone please guide me. Regards

Comment: Here: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/615

Comment: It seems like the OxyPlot for Windows apps package is not compatible with UWP C++/CX project, I see you leave a comment in here: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/615 You may open a new issue for this one

Comment: Yes, I left out the comment there because I am stuck in this issue. I have no clue where to go. If there is any other library compatible with (C++/Xaml) please tell me that I'll use that library.

Answer (score 0):

This may not 100% apply but it should. I was not trying to do this: "Use OxyPlot in Windows Universal app c++/xaml project". But I was tyring to use OxyPlot in a C++ .Net class so that it could do somethings fast, and eventually pass things back to a C# Class or WPF form. The idea I needed to know was could I create an OxyPlot.DataPoint array in C++ then put it into a C# Double array or an List in C# fast. And I can do that now fast! I hope this approach might help someone here doing this. I don't know how easy it is to use this technique to be able to use the opti chart in a C++ app or not. But if the GUI is done in C# this approach works.

I was getting the error: "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework." when I tried to install OptiPlot.WPF or the NuGet.Commandline.

This may not be a complete solution for everyone's needs, but it worked for me. I found a "cheatin" way of getting OptiPlot.WPF into a sample C++.Net project. I had a C# main program project in my solution - I installed the package there:
Install-Package OxyPlot.Wpf -Version 2.0.0

Then I copied the packages.config file and the packages folder from there to my C++ .Net Class Library Project. Then I edited the packages.config file and took something out that didn't apply, and I probably took out a package in packages that wasn't needed. Then I added my references in the C++ .Net Class Library Project to packages/OxyPlot.Wpf.2.0.0 folder.

Now I could use the OxyPlot inside of C++! Cool!